# Python indentation borked

Tags: python, vim, indentation

I saw that there are similar titles to this. But my case seems a little weirder. I somehow used a mixture of PyCharm and Vim (and within Vim I have tabstop=4 and shiftwidth=2), and my Python code seems un-fixabl-y borked, indentation-wise. I first saw that in Vim everything was mis-aligned, so I re-aligned everything; but then when I run it I get an error that there's an unexpected indentation, even though in Vim everything seems perfectly aligned. Here's an example (this is how it looks like in Vim):

```
for f in files:
    for line in f:
        items = line.strip().split()
        items = items[2:]
        items = ' '.join(items).split(', ')
```

When I run it, I get:

```
File "getEsSynonymLSAVectors.py", line 136
    items = items[2:]
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I used [PythonTidy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PythonTidy/1.22), I used `reindent`, I tried `:retab`, I tried manual re-aligning - nothing seems to fix this. Any experiences/ advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you upload the file anywhere, like [gist](http://gist.github.com) or [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)?

Comment: The code you posted (copy & pasted) doesn't have problems to me.

Comment: In vim, make sure you have `expandtab` set. Also, run Python with `-tt`. If it doesn't report an error, then look at the hexdump of the file — it might be buggily-handled Unicode whitespace or invisible characters.

Comment: Thanks everybody; apparently the problem is with my Vim settings. I tried to create a gist and it clearly shows the mis-alignment (the stuff that shows perfectly aligned in Vim). I tried the -tt option and it says inconsistent spaces and tabs (but at a line much before the line it's reporting an error on). I guess best is I just open the file, open another empty file on the side and re-type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python treated a tab as 8 spaces by default, if you get indentation borked, you'll generally want to switch the tabs to spaces (or vice versa, but I generally find that spaces are easier to deal with). So make sure to set vim to show tab as 8 spaces wide (`:set ts=8`), to see what python sees.

To fix tab errors in vim, I usually do the following, first I need to be able to see the tabs, so I enabled highlight search (`:set hlsearch`) and search for tabs (`/\t`). Then I eyeball the areas that needs to be retabbed. Next, I try to find the right vim tab width setting for the file (`:set ts=n` and vary `n` until everything looks good), enable expand tab (`:set et`), then run the automatic tab fixing (`:retab`). When all else fail, retab manually.

If you're using version control, make sure to diff with the files before the changes and manually check that you didn't introduce a bug because of unintentional changes in the indentation level. If you don't use version control,  keep a backup and run diff on the files.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.

First set appropriate settings. 
Always use 4 spaces. So change it to tabs = 4 spaces.

First convert all spaces to tabs.
And then convert all tabs to spaces.
(I use Geany)

It has worked for me before many times.